# exporting c++ dll to c# winform

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, dllimport, dllexport

I have these in my c++ header file

```
#ifndef S2dll_H
#define S2dll_H

#ifdef S2dll_EXPORTS
#define S2dll_API __declspec(dllexport)

#else
    #pragma message("automatic link to S2dll.LIB")
    #pragma comment(lib, "S2dll.lib")
#define S2dll_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

class is declared like this

```
class S2dll_API Sample
{
//members here
}
```

a cpp file containing function definitions, constructors

```
void * __stdcall CreateS() //constructor
{
    return new SDLL;
}


void __stdcall DestroyS(void * objPtr) //destructor
{
   s* sObj = (s *) objPtr;
    if (sobj)
        delete sObj;
}
```

exporting/exposing this function

```
void __stdcall setvaluesDLL(void *ptr, int x, int y,int s, int p)
    {


        Sample *dll =  (Sample *) ptr;

        if (dll)
        {
            dll->setposition(c); //functions in the cpp file
            dll->setlocation(x,y);
            dll->setsize(s);
        }

    }
```

a .def file

```
LIBRARY BS2dll

EXPORTS
CreateS
DestroyS
setvaluesDLL
```

so I am trying to access it in my c# win form

made this to expose it

```
static internal  class dllcall
{
[DllImport(@"adrress\S2dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void setvaluesDLL(IntPtr ptr,int x, int y, int s, int p);
}
```

calling it in my winform

```
private void Assign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dllcall.setvaluesDLL(ptr, x, y, s, p);//all values are int
 }
```

I get this error:
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

been searching google and staring at this code for hours and every time I manage to solve a problem, a new one comes out whenever I call `setvaluesDLL(//parameters)`

EDITED:
IntPtr ptr is my main problem here and I have absolutely no idea how to use nor initialize it

Comment: You forgot the 1st argument, `void *ptr`.  That needs to be declared as IntPtr in your C# code.

Comment: sorry to sound stupid or something but how would I assign the value for 'IntPtr ptr'? Is it a constructor or how should I initiaize/declare it?

Comment: Add IntPtr class member to C# class. Declare CreateS function with return type IntPtr in C#, call it and assign to this class member. Add first parameter IntPtr to CreateS, DestroyS and setvaluesDLL functions in C#.

Comment: Your native C wrapper is OK, you only need to fix C# PInvoke code. IntPtr is just .NET wrapper for void* pointer.

Comment: Probably in setvaluesDLL setposition(c) should be setposition(p)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize first setvaluesDLL parameter value with CreateS() result. This method should be imported from the dll too. The same as DestroyS - to release memory properly

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 arguments in your C++ file:

```
void __stdcall setvaluesDLL(void *ptr, int x, int y,int s, int p)
```

And only 4 in the C#:

```
public static extern void setvaluesDLL(int x, int y, int s, int p)
```

Also I don't think there's a direct equivalent to a void* pointer, so you might want to use unsafe code (you need to allow it in your project settings).

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you cannot explicitly import a c++ class in C# (to initialize ptr in Assign_Click). Maybe you could write some functions in the dll to render it available to C# -- or you could delve into the assembly.